# VBA Access: Can't seem to associate new menu items in pre-existing option button menu on form

Tags: vba

Recently we had to do a massive overhaul to a report that was written by my predecessor, the strangest problem I seem to be having is that it has an options menu, which as the report runs, it filters down through.

Now, we've had to add some new options to the report, only the new option buttons won't associate themselves properly with the menu and I'm at a loss as to why this might be.  Unfortunately the report does not run correctly without these option buttons being properly associated.

When I'm in design mode, the option buttons show the sunken actively clicked image, but when they're in form mode, they're grayed out as if they're not a selection.  I'm pretty sure I set them up correctly, but I'm going to go with "I did not set them up correctly" and can't seem to figure out why they won't associate properly.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rewpbkmyx7d336/option%20button%20issue.png?dl=0

Comment: You don't mention how/where the option buttons are being initialized, or if they are bound controls. I don't understand the relationship between 'menu' and 'options'. Are you meaning menu items on your application's Menu Bar? Or do you just mean clicking an option button should fire an event and execute VBA code?

Comment: Really sorry, been a busy week, forgot I should probably add some more details.  The option buttons have been set up like a menu on the form.  As far as I can tell it initializes the values of the options in a _AfterUpdate()  using the button name (Option10006 for example).  There doesn't seem to be any code that specifically sets the association for the table, so it may be completely disconnected for all I know.  For some reason I cannot activate the buttons properly so they can be selected.  They are in the "off" position when the form is active and "on" position in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting peoples time, I figured out the issue, the new options weren't housing themselves in the Option Group.